# HttpURLConnection c = URL.openConnection(); c.setRequestProperty() Doesn't work

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, android-c2dm

This Code here is a normal Java application not an android application, this is designed to send C2DM messages to a device with YOUR_REGISTRATION_STRING as the developer with auth_key, the problem is described below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;


public class C2DMSendMessage {
    private final static String AUTH = "authentication";

    private static final String UPDATE_CLIENT_AUTH = "Update-Client-Auth";

    public static final String PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID = "registration_id";

    public static final String PARAM_DELAY_WHILE_IDLE = "delay_while_idle";

    public static final String PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY = "collapse_key";

    private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

    // Registration is currently hardcoded
    private final static String YOUR_REGISTRATION_STRING = "APA91bGf8gkFMn_sBP_hosSAiqUmmLwOdIqVSQKbbqXv2WSADQ51gbixInAGUk1U_vDIcz7izVaq6tvu8KXGsiQ7BIKy_7f04id00SUms8h3YGxbsKd6Jjg";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
        String auth_key = "DQAAAA4BAADAb7BDi6KY9pj11ERiY0R1TaEynLK6AtSPxzzIeCih_VDyWLhEJCvmkXjh6gRAsGpLb0wtAGmWIK9CjsBMT3upjnZ86tRYnvfOknkN45ORk29AsR2he-JEo1Y4eVcUutoPnBbIX2kzoEeY2ULYXyOQix7oWSWb4CJS3XYrb7qcmQxMv3yiIAF8kO0Sav7-NspCSI3tV3lISrz_BWqSCVGHWxT6KZ_PZwjH7442CpMfZhOYxsgDanQod8EypHjHmNQK_txWwFeiFj66jsi90BpyPKvUX_ZUbOmSKVZP3gBcKrK9iSnJrSUpLuEN46NGRzl2uBg9I9V-wJuFBgG1aBXqA1oWFdkEewxwXapuVqR1-g";
        // Send a sync message to this Android device.
        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        postDataBuilder.append(PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID).append("=")
                .append(YOUR_REGISTRATION_STRING);

        // if (delayWhileIdle) {
        // postDataBuilder.append("&").append(PARAM_DELAY_WHILE_IDLE)
        // .append("=1");
        // }
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append(PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY).append("=")
                .append("0");

        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=")
                .append(URLEncoder.encode("Lars war hier", UTF8));

        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        // Hit the dm URL.

        URL url = new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="
                + auth_key);
        System.out.println(conn.getRequestProperties());
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(responseCode));
        // Validate the response code

        if (responseCode == 401 || responseCode == 403) {
            // The token is too old - return false to retry later, will
            // fetch the token
            // from DB. This happens if the password is changed or token
            // expires. Either admin
            // is updating the token, or Update-Client-Auth was received by
            // another server,
            // and next retry will get the good one from database.
            System.out.println("Unauthorized - need token");
        }

        // Check for updated token header
        String updatedAuthToken = conn.getHeaderField(UPDATE_CLIENT_AUTH);
        if (updatedAuthToken != null && !auth_key.equals(updatedAuthToken)) {
            System.out.println("Got updated auth token from datamessaging servers: "
                            + updatedAuthToken);
        }

        String responseLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream())).readLine();

        // NOTE: You *MUST* use exponential backoff if you receive a 503
        // response code.
        // Since App Engine's task queue mechanism automatically does this
        // for tasks that
        // return non-success error codes, this is not explicitly
        // implemented here.
        // If we weren't using App Engine, we'd need to manually implement
        // this.
        if (responseLine == null || responseLine.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Got " + responseCode
                    + " response from Google AC2DM endpoint.");
            throw new IOException(
                    "Got empty response from Google AC2DM endpoint.");
        }

        String[] responseParts = responseLine.split("=", 2);
        if (responseParts.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid message from google: " + responseCode
                    + " " + responseLine);
            throw new IOException("Invalid response from Google "
                    + responseCode + " " + responseLine);
        }

        if (responseParts[0].equals("id")) {
            System.out.println("Successfully sent data message to device: "
                    + responseLine);
        }

        if (responseParts[0].equals("Error")) {
            String err = responseParts[1];
            System.out.println("Got error response from Google datamessaging endpoint: "
                            + err);
            // No retry.
            throw new IOException(err);
        }
    }
}
```

in the code above i'm attempting to send a C2DM Message but it's irrelevant

```
URL url = new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",Integer.toString(postData.length));
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="+ auth_key);
System.out.println(conn.getRequestProperties());
```

in the portion that i have repeated i am attempting to set request properties 3 of them but only 1 ever reaches the hashmap in conn
this is the output :

> {Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8]}

I don't understand how that code can run if it's on it's own just those lines
and not work as part of a bigger code

i also tried it with addRequestProperty

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of setting Content-Length in the request property, use setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postData.length);

According to the source for [HttpUrlConnection](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.html) , Content-Length is a "restricted header":

```
146       /*
147        * Restrict setting of request headers through the public api
148        * consistent with JavaScript XMLHttpRequest2 with a few
149        * exceptions. Disallowed headers are silently ignored for
150        * backwards compatibility reasons rather than throwing a
151        * SecurityException. For example, some applets set the
152        * Host header since old JREs did not implement HTTP 1.1.
153        * Additionally, any header starting with Sec- is
154        * disallowed.
155        *
156        * The following headers are allowed for historical reasons:
157        *
158        * Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Cookie2, Date,
159        * Referer, TE, User-Agent, headers beginning with Proxy-.
160        *
161        * The following headers are allowed in a limited form:
162        *
163        * Connection: close
164        *
165        * See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2.
166        */
167       private static final boolean allowRestrictedHeaders;
168       private static final Set<String> restrictedHeaderSet;
169       private static final String[] restrictedHeaders = {
170           /* Restricted by XMLHttpRequest2 */
171           //"Accept-Charset",
172           //"Accept-Encoding",
173           "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
174           "Access-Control-Request-Method",
175           "Connection", /* close is allowed */
176           "Content-Length",
177           //"Cookie",
178           //"Cookie2",
179           "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
180           //"Date",
181           //"Expect",
182           "Host",
183           "Keep-Alive",
184           "Origin",
185           // "Referer",
186           // "TE",
187           "Trailer",
188           "Transfer-Encoding",
189           "Upgrade",
190           //"User-Agent",
191           "Via"
192       };
```

So, setting Content-Length will be silently ignored.

Authorization is blocked from being returned for security purposes:

```
249       // the following http request headers should NOT have their values
250       // returned for security reasons.
251       private static final String[] EXCLUDE_HEADERS = {
252               "Proxy-Authorization",
253               "Authorization"
254       };
255   
256       // also exclude system cookies when any might be set
257       private static final String[] EXCLUDE_HEADERS2= {
258               "Proxy-Authorization",
259               "Authorization",
260               "Cookie",
261               "Cookie2"
262       };
```

So even if you set the authorization header, you won't get it back when you query the headers.

Comment: i replaced the content length line with conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postdata.length); still the output is The Request Properties: {Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8]}
the authorization was never entered in the request properties :/, note that i also tried not setting the length at all

Comment: as you see n my code i am using 
import java.net.HttpURLConnection; not the sun httpurl,  eclipse just won't use the sun one

Comment: The HttpURLConnection is doesn't allow you to set content length, and won't report it back to you.  Authorization is specifically excluded from being returned in the properties map.  I've updated and expanded my original answer to include a few more comments.

Comment: The "sun httpurl" is the implementation delegate class for HttpURLConnection when using the stock Java vm.  If you step into the setRequestProperty method in Eclipse, it'll eventually get to this implementation delegate.  That's how I found the answer.

Comment: i don't know why but my code doesn't work, and another code posted here on stackoverflow also doesn't work, i'm gonna try other alternatives, but as far as i am concerned your answer was correct thanks

Comment: What's not working?  Dumping the parameters is giving you the correct result.  Authorization is being set, you just can't see it in map because the implementation is specifically suppressing it when you get the map back.  Content-Length is silently ignored when you set it, and won't be displayed in the map either, even when calling setFixedLengthStreamingMode.

Comment: the error was a logic error, i set a wrong email at the client, but you are right, i asked about set/get/add ResultPropert(ies/y) and you are right it execludes authorization it was sent all along i'm the clumsy one, thanks very much mate

Answer (score 1):

The content length is set automatically. You can't set it yourself directly. You can however pass the correct length when setting fixed length streaming mode.

Comment: The method setFixedLengthStreamingMode is used for this purpose.  From the JavaDoc: "This method is used to enable streaming of a HTTP request body without internal buffering, when the content length is known in advance."

Comment: I removed it and still the Authorization is never actually getting into the request properties

Comment: Again, you won't be able to read it back...the implementation in the java runtime restricts that header for security reasons.  Inspect your traffic with a protocol sniffer, like Fiddler.  You should see an Authorization header in the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can add this line in your code to solve it.

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841662/15201439