# HttpURLConnection - Authorization Header is missing?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to set an Authorization header to my http request but when I dump the headers before commiting the request I cannpt see the Authorization header!

this is the setting code:

```
    public void addRequestHeaders(HttpURLConnection a_urlConnection, UserData a_userData) {

    a_urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",          "application/json");
    a_urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Client-Information",  "zzzzzzzzzzz");

    String sAuthorization = createAuthorizationCode(a_userData);
    String sAuthorizationEncoded = "Basic " + EncriptionManager.getInstance().Base64Encript(sAuthorization);
    a_urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", sAuthorizationEncoded);


    Dumpers.dumpRequest(a_urlConnection, m_sRequestBody);
}
```

And the dumping code is:

```
    public static void dumpRequest(HttpURLConnection  a_httpConnection, String a_sRequestBody) {

    System.out.println("HttpPostRequest : sendHttpRequest: URL = " + a_httpConnection.getURL().toExternalForm());
    System.out.println("HttpPostRequest : sendHttpRequest: Request Body = " + a_sRequestBody);

    for (String header : a_httpConnection.getRequestProperties().keySet()) {
       if (header != null) {
         for (String value : a_httpConnection.getRequestProperties().get(header)) {
            System.out.println(header + ":" + value);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
HttpPostRequest : sendHttpRequest: URL = https://ahemli-   nexus.connectrnd.com/Att.Auth.Api/v1/authentication
HttpPostRequest : sendHttpRequest: Request Body = 
X-Client-Information:zzzzzzzzzzz
Content-Type:application/json
```

Can you advise please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

And this is the answer...

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564015/httpurlconnection-c-url-openconnection-c-setrequestproperty-doesnt-work)

Authorization header is hidden by default..