# RestTemplate not passing Origin header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a cross-origin request using Spring's RestTemplate. The communication is done between two Spring-boot webapps, both running on localhost but different port. What I do is:

```java
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setOrigin("http://localhost:8083");
httpHeaders.add("Authorization", token);

HttpEntity<Void> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObj>> beanType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyObj>>() {};
ResponseEntity<List<MyObj>> list = restTemplate.exchange(serviceURL, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, beanType);
```

The call is executed, the "Authorization" header is passed just fine, but no matter what I try, there is no "Origin" header on the receiving side.
When I create a simillar request using some other tool (SoapUI, RestClient Chrome plugin, etc.) the header is passed just as I provide it.

To print all headers on the receiving side I'm using a implementation of javax.servlet.Filter with:

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        log.info(headerName + ": " + request.getHeader(headerName));
    }
}
```

Why is the origin header not passed when using RestTemplate?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Had the same problem which I spent a century to fix.

The root cause is this line from the RestTemplate documentation

> Note: by default the RestTemplate relies on standard JDK facilities to establish HTTP connections.

If you check source code of `HttpUrlConnection` class in Java, you'll find below block of code, and header `Origin` is one of the restricted headers that forbid changes:

```
/*
 * Restrict setting of request headers through the public api
 * consistent with JavaScript XMLHttpRequest2 with a few
 * exceptions. Disallowed headers are silently ignored for
 * backwards compatibility reasons rather than throwing a
 * SecurityException. For example, some applets set the
 * Host header since old JREs did not implement HTTP 1.1.
 * Additionally, any header starting with Sec- is
 * disallowed.
 *
 * The following headers are allowed for historical reasons:
 *
 * Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Cookie2, Date,
 * Referer, TE, User-Agent, headers beginning with Proxy-.
 *
 * The following headers are allowed in a limited form:
 *
 * Connection: close
 *
 * See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2.
 */
 private static final boolean allowRestrictedHeaders;
 private static final Set<String> restrictedHeaderSet;
 private static final String[] restrictedHeaders = {
    /* Restricted by XMLHttpRequest2 */
    //"Accept-Charset",
    //"Accept-Encoding",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Connection", /* close is allowed */
    "Content-Length",
    //"Cookie",
    //"Cookie2",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
    //"Date",
    //"Expect",
    "Host",
    "Keep-Alive",
    "Origin",
    // "Referer",
    // "TE",
    "Trailer",
    "Transfer-Encoding",
    "Upgrade",
    //"User-Agent",
    "Via"
};
```

There is a easy fix to this problem, just to set a JVM argument

```
-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
```

or add a line in your code

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
```

which suppress the restriction.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem. I've found out that apache http client don't have this problem and sends request with 'Origin': http://hc.apache.org/

```
HttpOptions httpOptions = new 
HttpOptions(url)
httpOptions.setHeader("Origin", "test")
httpOptions.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
BasicHttpClientConnectionManager manager = new 
BasicHttpClientConnectionManager()
HttpClient client = new MinimalHttpClient(manager)
client.execute(httpOptions)
```